# Telnet iPhone Application that connect through iPhone USB port

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, telnet

I am looking for a weekend project to do and I was wondering if this was possible.  I have these radios that are programmed using Telnet (to set the frequencies, output power, etc.) and I normally do this with my computer in the terminal.  The radios have an RS-232 connector on them and I use a USB converter to connect to my computer.  Having a small, portable device to program them with instead of a big, clunky laptop would be great, so what I am hoping is possible is to be able to create a telnet connection with my iPhone.  Is it possible to create a Telnet application for my iPhones that can connect to these radios through the USB/lightning port on the iPhone?  I know normally when people write Telnet applications for the iPhone, they are using over the air connections like WiFi/3G/4G to connect to the internet, but this radio is not connected to the internet but its own private network of other radios.  If it is possible to connect the iPhone to the RS-232 port and accomplish the Telnet connection (also without frying my iPhone with too much current) that would be fantastic.  Also, if it is possible, how would I access the lightning port?  Thanks!

EDIT:  Another possible connection is the iPhones lightning port to an RJ-45 connection.  That would work as well.  Is this possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can always study the specification of the lightning connector, you can find it here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_(connector). You can try to play with the SDK, trying to send commands from the iPhone and receiving information through the cable. The problem of that, and I was working in several medical applications with the 30 pin connector and the lightning as well, is you have to spend a lot of time to deal with the specification. The most important part is to understand how the connector works and what can you send and receive through the cable. If not, you would have to build your own connector, which is interesting and can help to learn a lot, but it´s not an easy thing. In a project I was working, we had to build several cables to adapt the signals to connect with the device, in my case an iPad1 and recently an iPad 4 although it works with the iPhone as well. As you know, or you should, you will have to learn about MFI. 
You can find some information regarding that point here : [Create an iPad app that can send/receive data via the USB cable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668887/create-an-ipad-app-that-can-send-receive-data-via-the-usb-cable), but bear in mind everything goes through MFI, so it has its pros and cons....most of them cons. You can find several information here : https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

good luck :)