# CoreMidi: How do I send MIDI through the lightning cable?

Tags: ios, coremidi

I am looking to send MIDI signals through the lightning cable to the MIDI network on my laptop.

Is there anyway to do this?

The MIDINetworkConnection class has a connectionWithHost method, that allows wifi connections. But I'm looking for something faster, so I'm wondering if we can do that.

Answer (score 2):

macOS and iOS now do this natively with IDAM (inter-device audio and MIDI).

1. Attach an iOS device to your Mac and unlock it.
2. If prompted to trust, trust the host Mac.
3. Launch Audio MIDI Setup.
4. If not visible, show the Audio Device window (Cmd + 1)
5. Click the "Enable" button next to the iOS device.
6. A MIDI device called "iPhone" or "iPad" will show up in the MIDI Setup.
7. On the iOS device, route MIDI to the IDAM MIDI Host destination.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it natively, but there is a way to use the lightning cable as a network interface to send data to the computer.

The new version of [touchAble](http://www.touch-able.com/) does that, but it requires a server application that runs on the computer, talking to the device and opening a virtual MIDI port to route the MIDI messages to your DAW.

You might need to check the [Apple MFi program](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action), if it is not out of scope, depending on the nature of your project. Or check [that other discussion about USB communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668887/create-an-ipad-app-that-can-send-receive-data-via-the-usb-cable).